# Replacing strings in files with regex

Tags: regex, shell

I've manually removed some superfluous //-------------------------------------
comments from all c++ files within a folder and its subfolders [here](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/#/c/8170/) .

Now I thought that it might be possible to replace `"//<unknown number of dashes><line break>"` with an empty string or a line break via a shell script.

Afterwards I'd want to replace three consecutive line breaks with two line breaks.

Could someone tell me how to achieve this with a shell script?

Comment: C++ or Shell script? You tag it C++ while talking about shell script in question. Please make it clear.

Comment: I meant a shell command/script to remove comments from c++ files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all C++ style comments that contain only dashes and optional trailing whitespace:

```
sed 's|//--* *$||' -i file.cpp
```

To remove trailing whitespace:

```
sed 's/ *$//' -i file.cpp
```

Comment: Does that also remove useful comments?

Comment: Sorry. yes, it does. I'll edit the post immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I added SzG's command to this one to get it to run recursively:

```
find . -name '*.cxx' | xargs sed 's|// --* *$||' -i
```